# Getting name of each open PPT presentation using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to get the name of each open PPT presentation using the following code.
Problem is that I get the error message "ActiveX component can't create object" in the "For each"-line of the code.

Thanks in advance for your help!

PS: Weird thing: I copied the code EXCACTLY from here: http://vba.relief.jp/powerpoint-macro-get-all-open-presentations-name/

```
Sub GetAllOpenPresentationsName()

Dim prs As Presentation


For Each prs In Presentations

Debug.Print prs.Name

Next prs

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you executing this from within Powerpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. It seems you are not working in PowerPoint VBA. if working from other platform try

```
Sub GetAllOpenPresentationsName()
Dim prs As Presentation
Dim PP As PowerPoint.Application
On Error Resume Next
Set PP = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
    If Err Then
    Debug.Print "PowerPoint is not Open"
    Err.Clear
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error GoTo 0
For Each prs In PP.Presentations
Debug.Print prs.Name
Next prs
End Sub
```

Comment: QHarr: No in Excel, I think that was the problem
Ahmed AU: Thank you very much! It worked perfectly :)